# Stateless Asp.Net MVC disables some features of EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am reading a book on ASP.NET MVC, where the author has mentioned that due to the stateless nature of ASP.NET MVC some of the features in Entity Framework are disabled.

With that in mind, it is best to abstract the data access layer. The Repository pattern is one of the most used patterns for managing data abstraction.

I am curious to know, what are the features  of EF will be disabled, if Repository pattern is not used for data abstraction.

Comment: er, which book is that then? what version of MVC? What version of EF? Give us a chance here!

Comment: It is book from microsoft for Exam 70-486, it doesn't specify the version of MVC and EF.

Answer (score 2):

I am reading the same Exam 70-486 book.
**Entity Framework can't have the DbContextObject (the old ObjectContext) object live for the whole user session, this means that Entity Framework can't track changes to the entity object in a web application**.
The solution is to create a new DbContextObject  object each time we need to make some operations against a database.

However, this solution is causing one problem, when we need to delete or update a record with the new instance of DbContextObject. One first solution is to retrieve first the object that you are trying to modify, and only then do the necessary changes. Another solution would be to mark the entity state as modified (
*context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;*) without the need to retrieve the entity first

Answer (score 0):

In particular, entity tracking is not very useful, because you have new object instance on each request. Workaround for update is:

```
var entity = new Entity();
entity.Id = id;
content.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```